# Rails rake db:seed and FactoryGirl not getting along

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, factory-bot

Trying to use FactoryGirl to seed my development db with some data. Following [this](http://xtargets.com/2011/02/06/seeding-your-rails-db-with-factory-girl/) tutorial so my seeds.rb file looks like this:

```
require 'factory_girl'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/factories/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

100.times do
  FactoryGirl.create :idea
end
```

When running `rake db:seed` it complains:

```
rake aborted!
Factory already registered: idea
```

Why is it a bad thing that the factory is registered? I'm trying to use it, not register it (whatever that means...). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your factories are already being loaded. Try removing the line that does each of the requires and see if that corrects the issue.

Comment: Bingo! Could you explain why my factories were already loaded? What made Rails load them like that? (Thanks for the quick answer!)

Comment: Most likely you're raking with RAILS_ENV=test and FactoryGirl is in your Gemfile under the test group, causing it to be automatically loaded in that environment.